Scss changes are not modified in css file
I have created style.scss and style.css file but when I did changes in the style.scss then it do not get reflected automatically into css file.
I have tried following commands also
npm install -g sass
after running this below command error is shwoing
sass style.scss style.css
Error:
sass : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\sass.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled
on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

sass style.scss style.css

  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess




It seems like the device policy of your actual machine prevents the running of the powershell script (ps1 filetype) sass that converts the scss to css.
Can I recommend contacting your administrator of your device to whitelist the scss script being run, or use an external converter like
https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css
